# Creating HTTP Alias for Subversion repos directories

Tags: svn

I would like to grant read/write access for one of our development team to access only a particular sub directory in a SVN repository. I achieved this using the directive "AuthzSVNAccessFile" in subversion.conf(httpd).

Let Say I am having the following directory structure in my svn repo:
 - Workspace
      - Branches
            
         - Mobile
                  
             - App
                        
               - Phase1
                        
               - Phase2
                        
               - Phase3 (This is the directory I want to grant)
               .....

Phase3 can be accessible by our dev team using the below url
      
          http://mydomain.com/svn/Workspace/Branches/Mobile/App/Phase3

How do I create a short url like the following to access the above one.
      
          http://mydomain.com/svn/Phase3

Please help me to get this done. Thanks.

My apache configurations are below:
<Location /Phase3>
    
   DAV svn
    
   ReWriteEngine On
    
   ReWriteRule ^Phase3$  Workspace/Branches/Mobile/App/Phase3
    
   SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
    
   AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/www/svn/Workspace/conf/authz
    
   Require valid-user
    
   AuthType Basic
    
   AuthName "Subversion repositories"
    
   AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
</Location>

Comment: By using the rewrite module? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I tried rewrite module too. But It doesn't work.

Comment: And "It doesn't work" means what? Are we meant to _guess_ that?

Comment: Sorry for my bad communication. It's not working.

Comment: Short URL - long headache. Can't see benefits here - URL will be entered only once and can be copy&past'ed also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preface**: I never used it for SVN-locations and I'll try to avoid it in future, but you have to test. I can't explain in simple words, why I try to avoid `Alias` directive, you can think about it as about my "interbal voice"

**Face**:

I consider mod_rewrite for this simple case as overkill and suggest to start with mod_alias. ["...mod_alias is designed to handle simple URL manipulation tasks..."](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html)

Inside corresponding container (location or vhost, but I'll start from **outside and before** SVN-Location definition)

`Redirect /svn/Phase3 /svn/Workspace/Branches/Mobile/App/Phase3`

If Phase3 in turn, is node, not leaf, you may to have to use `RedirectMatch` directive